# Copy lines longer than terminal window

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Is it possible to copy a line that extends past the edge of the viewable window in GNU screen?

When I press Ctrl-a [ and then hit space, I can only move to the edge of the visible window, even though the line extends further. I am trying to copy a line from a file open in vim and then paste it into a different screen.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are trying to use screen or tmux copying capability, but vim has its own, as described by @schurik. It is not possible to copy full line from vim without using vim capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

in vim you can use * buffer to copy into the clipboard and V to mark the whole line:
thus im normal mode press:

```
V"*y
```

to copy the line under cursor into the clipboard

Comment: Or just `"*yy` (avoid going into visual mode). If that doesn't work, try the + buffer. To paste, `"*p` to paste from the * buffer.